# Stack View not getting added as a subview programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, subview, uistackview

I have an array of buttons which I have added within a stackview, I need to add this stackView in one of my subview which is in another parentStackView. 
This is my code:

```
        let innerStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttonViews(withTitleArray: buttonTitleArray, numberArray: ButtonTagArray))
        innerStackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        innerStackView.axis = .vertical
        innerStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        innerStackView.alignment = .fill
        innerStackView.spacing = 5
        innerStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mainView.bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        mainView.bottomView.addSubview(innerStackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerStackView.leadingAnchor),
            mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerStackView.trailingAnchor),
            mainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerStackView.widthAnchor),
            mainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerStackView.heightAnchor)])
       mainView.alpha = 1
        mainView.clipsToBounds = true
        parentstackView.addArrangedSubview(mainView)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

The issue is that even though I can see the mainView in my parentStackView, the inner stackview is not visible. I can't seem to understand why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are adding it as a subview of the bottomView. Can you see the bottomView (background color is red)?

Comment: Check constraints of your `bottomView`.

Comment: @wottle yes I can see the red color, i cant see the green color of inner stackView

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev its tied to its parentView

Comment: Why wouldn't you set the constraints of the innerStackView to its parent, the bottomView? Why use the mainView for its constraints?

Comment: Use anchors of `bottomView` for `innerStackView`

Comment: *"i cant see the green color of inner stackView"* `UIStackView` is non-rendering... so you won't see a "background color" even if you try to set it.

Comment: Log you stackView frame after ```self.view.layoutIfNeeded()```, it can be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, So I couldn't find a solution programmatically, I ended up making the `bottomView` in the interface builder and binding it with the `mainview`  with the help of constraints.That did the trick for me.